# C file operation question

Tags: c

```
file * fp = fopen()
file * fd = ????
```

I want to use `*fd` to write file which `*fp` opened before.

How can I do it?

Add some, the key of this question is use another pointer to do it. See, *fd is the different pointer. Wish i made this clear.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
file* fd = fp;
```

If I understand you correctly, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Use `fwrite`, `fputc`, `fprintf`, or `fputs`, depending on what you need.

With `fputc`, you can put a `char`:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "w");
fputc('A', fp); // will put an 'A' (65) char to the file
```

With `fputs`, you can put a `char` array (string):

```
FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "w");
fputs("a string", fp); // will write "a string" to the file
```

With `fwrite` you could also write binary data:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "wb");
int a = 31272;
fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
// will write integer value 31272 to the file
```

With `fprintf` you could write formatted data:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "w");
int a = 31272;
fprintf(fp, "a's value is %d", 31272);
// will write string "a's value is 31272" to the file
```